# Grouping factor variable

Tags: r, dplyr

My factor variable -- var1-- has 7 levels to it, but I want to group levels 5-7 together.

I am thinking about doing something like

```
ifelse(var1 >= 5 ~ '5+', var1)
```

but this logic is not working.

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output.  The `~` is used in `case_when`, here, it would be `ifelse(var1 >= 5, "5+", var1)`

Comment: It really was that easy. Sorry about that. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The `ifelse` doesn't use `~`, it would be `,` for `yes` and `no` arguments

```
ifelse(var1 >= 5, "5+", var1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of your desired output, but since you refer to a numeric
5 and wish to replace this with a character "5+" I would recommend something like the following using the mutate verb in dplyr:

```
library(dplyr)
data <- data.frame(response = seq(1,14), var1 = rep(1:7))
data <- data %>% mutate(var1 = factor(ifelse(var1 >= 5, "5+", var1)))
levels(data$var1)
```